# Import em diretorios diferentes em Python3

Tags: python-3.x

Boa noite,

Estou arduamente tendando realizar um simples import de modúlos criados por mim mesmo, para o meu codigo principal. Com tudo sempre recebo o segunte erro

"attempted relative import with no known parent package"

Segue a estrutura do meu projeto.

```
<DIR> Projeto
------<DIR> config_file
-----------<DIR> func_file
----------------<FILE> __init__.py
----------------<FILE> modulo1.py
----------------<FILE> modulo2.py
------<FILE> config.py
<FILE> main.py
```

No caso dessa hierarquia, qual seria o modo correto de realizar os imports ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode simplesmente dar o nome dos diretórios separados por `.` na hora de importar. Por exemplo, se estou trabalhando no diretório `dir0` e se meu pacote `mod.py` está em `dir0/dir1/dir2/mod.py`, posso fazer:

```
import dir1.dir2.mod
```

De acordo com o livro do [Lutz](https://www.amazon.com.br/Learning-Python-Mark-Lutz/dp/1449355730) (capítulo 24), esse tipo de importação relativa exige que as seguintes regras sejam observadas:

1. dir1 e dir2 devem conter um arquivo `__init__.py`.
2. dir0, o `cwd`, não requer um arquivo `__init__.py`; esse arquivo
   simplesmente será ignorado se presente.
3. dir0, não dir0 \ dir1, deve estar listado no caminho de pesquisa do
   módulo `sys.path`.

Portanto, para o seu caso (supondo que você está trabalhando na pasta `Projeto`), bastaria fazer:

```
import config_file.func_file.modulo1
import config_file.func_file.modulo1
```

Todas as propriedades de importações comuns permanecem válidas. Além do `from`, também é possível utilizar os `as` para reduzir a inconveniência de usar nomes longos. Para o modulo1, por exemplo, teríamos:

```
import config_file.func_file.modulo1 as mod1
```

Leia o capítulo 24 do livro citado para mais detalhes sobre importação de módulos no Python.

---

> EDIT: Mudando o path para realizar a importação direta

A importação relativa funciona da forma como descrito acima. Contudo, também existe a opção de realizar a importação de forma absoluta, o que tem a vantagem de você não precisar ficar recordando o tempo todo o desenho do diretório e, além disso, você pode importar módulos externos ao diretório atual.

Para fazer a importação absoluta basta adicionar o `path` onde encontram-se os módulos definidos pelo usuário à lista de paths já utilizadas por default. Para ver a lista default de paths, basta fazer:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

E para adicionar um path à lista, digite:

```
sys.path.append("PATH/dir0/dir1/dir2/")
```

Onde `PATH` é o path no seu computador até a pasta `dir0`.

E aí basta realizar a importação direta:

```
import mod
```

Comment: O jeito correto de utilizar o `import` de um modulo de dentro de vários diretórios é utilizar o __from__, caso alguém utilize o jeito que descreveu, quando for utilizar o que esta sendo importado, a pessoa terá que usar o caminho completo novamente por exemplo __a = config_file.func_file.modulo1.metodo_dentro_do_arquivo__

Comment: As duas formas estão corretas. O inconveniente do nome grande não impede que a importação funcione e, além disso, essa inconveniência pode ser facilmente superada usando `as` como é amplamente sabido. A sua resposta está errada ao afirmar que a importação com o `from` é condição necessária para a importação relativa funcionar. Além disso, você também errou ao colocar na sua resposta a extensão do arquivo a ser importado. A importação precisa ser feita sem declarar a extensão do arquivo.

Comment: Desculpa, mas se devemos passar alguma instrução, que seja de um jeito que seja mais fácil para o aprendizado e não algo que dificulte, não é que funciona que esta certo, se alguém esta aprendendo algo, que seja do melhor jeito e que seja melhor para o aprendizado, eu podeira descrever em uma reposta que funciona no Python 2.7 e no 3, porem logo o Python perdera suporte para o Python 2.7 e isso causaria problemas para aqueles que terão que concertar seus códigos logo após o acontecimento, devemos ser intuitivo, um exemplo

Comment: Sim a importação não precisa da extensão, foi um erro de digitação, mas não o negativei por maldade ou má fé, porém não vejo como uma reposta útil de acordo com o que descrevi acima

Comment: Pois é, mas se na sua opinião minha resposta só precisava de um ajuste para ficar mais fácil para o autor da pergunta, o mais ético era comentar isso e eu editaria em seguida.

Comment: desculpa, mas não é uma cópia, diversas perguntas eu tinha argumentos e deixei de responder por ja ter uma reposta completa, publiquei minha reposta por ter algo a mais a incrementar algo que a sua reposta não teve, basta ler ambas as perguntas, não sou eu que decido quem esta certo, mas se vejo conteúdo que deveria se acrescentado, acho que o melhor é expor eles e sim, eu iria fazer um comentário sim aqui para você descrevendo o porque, apenas não tive tempo de terminar e removeria a negativação da minha parte caso tenha sido modificada

Answer (score 1):

creio que já conheça o 'import', porem, para caminho maiores você utiliza o `from`
irei da uns exemplos para ficar mais claro

> lembrando que depende também da `env` se estiver utilizando mas um exemplo de acordo com o que foi passado

```
# config.py

from config_file.func_file import modulo1
```

ou dependendo se estiver usando o venv pode ser esse abaixo

```
# config.py

from Projeto.config_file.func_file import modulo1
```

> Você também pode importa tudo em uma pasta se utiliza o `*`, por exemplo

```
# config.py

from config_file.func_file import *
```

### Agora algo interessante sobre o **init** e todo o conteúdo dentro do mesmo local

o **init** é o primeiro local que o Python olha quando você chama o `import` para a pasta

os módulos funciona de um jeito diferente quando usamos eles como se fosse módulos, tirando a necessidade de colocar o caminho completo quando a importação é dentro deles

vamos escrever algumas coisas no `__init__`

```
# config_file/func_file/__init__.py

from . import modulo1, modulo2
```

perceba que para o caminho atual dos arquivos classificados como módulos é apenas um `.`

e desse jeito você pode importar somente até a pasta onde se encontra o `__init__`

```
# config.py

from config_file import func_file
```

e perceba que você consegue usar tudo que esta nessa pasta, como `config_file.metodo2.metodo_dentro_do_arquivo`

ou até mesmo fazer assim

```
# config_file/func_file/__init__.py

from .modulo1 import *
from .modulo2 import *
```

e chamaram dentro do seu arquivo main assim

```
# config.py

from config_file import func_file

config_file.metodo_dentro_do_arquivo     # sendo o que estiver dentro de ambos os metodos.py
```